# How to get all McDonalds places in Australia with google places api

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

Is there any way to get all McDonalds in Australia from google places api? When you go to maps.google.com, search sydney, then search "McDonalds", then zoom out until you can see all of Australia then you can see that google maps is capable of this but I cant figure out how to do it myself.

If I use their APIs at https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search then I can only get 20 results returned, with up to 3 pages of results. However when you use their map they can support more than 60 results. Does anyone know how to do this?

[image: All McDs in Australia]

Comment: What is the code (method) you have used can you provide more code or/and more specific method reference or the webservice API you have used

Comment: I have tried the nearbysearch api and it works fine but it only includes 60 results https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/output?parameters

Answer (score 1):

There is not currently a way to get **all** the McDonalds in Australia from the Places API.  There are two options:

- nearbySearch - up to 60 results in batches of 20
- radarSearch - up to 200 results, with less detail per result.